# A simpler refutation of the General Comprehension Principle?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The famous Russell's Paradox in which $R = \{ x \; | \; x \notin x \}$ leads to a contradiction

$$
R \in R \Longleftrightarrow R \notin R,
$$

thereby showing that the General Comprehension Principle entails inconsistency. But I think I found an even simpler refutation of it. We know that for some definite condition $P$

$$
A = \{ x \; | \; P(x) \} \Longleftrightarrow_{\text{df}} x \in A \Longleftrightarrow P(x) \text{ is true.}
$$

The General Comprehension Principle guarantees the existence of all such sets $A$, therefore we only have to find such $A$ that leads to contradiction to refute it. This is easy. Just take

$$
A = \{ x \; | \; x \notin A \} \Longleftrightarrow x \in A \Longleftrightarrow x \notin A
$$

by the above definition. Notice that this contradiction holds even if we assume that $A$ is the only set that exists, since we can still ask ourselves whether $A \in A$.

However, this almost seems *too easy*. I checked my truth tables again and again and couldn't find a mistake in my reasoning. The above equivalence truly seems like a contradiction no matter how I look at it. I would appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at a (careful) statement of the general comprehension principle, it will say something like: For any formula $\phi(x)$ in which $y$ is not free, $\exists y\forall x\,(x\in y\iff\phi(x))$. The proviso "in which $y$ is not free" prevents attempts to circularly define a set $y$ (or your $A$) in terms of itself.

This issue is not specific to the general comprehension principle. The separation axiom of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory has an analogous proviso: For any formula $\phi(x,z)$ in which $y$ is not free, $\exists y\forall x\,(x\in y\iff (x\in z\land\phi(x,z)))$. If the proviso were omitted here, we'd have a contradiction, just like yours, as soon as $z$ is nonempty. Analogous provisos also appear in the replacement axiom of ZF and in other set theories like NBG, MK, NF. And they're always needed for the same reason as in your question; circular definitions easily lead to contradictions.

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot. Though I don't understand why $\exists y\forall x\,(x\in y\iff (x\in z\land\phi(x,z)))$ leads to a contradiction when $z$ is not the empty set.

Comment: @GregorPerčič The contradiction, when $y$ is allowed to occur in $\phi(x,z)$, is the same as in your question: Take $\phi(x,z)$ to be $x\notin y$. Then instantiate $\forall x$ with any element $x$ of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $A=\{x\mid x\notin A\}$ is not a *definition*. It is an equation. The onus is on you to show that some object satisfies this equation. Of course, if $A$ was any set satisfying the equation, then we have a contradiction. So all we have shown is that this equation has no solutions, but that's nothing new: $x=x+1$ is an equation without solutions (in $\Bbb R$, anyway).

Note that in the case of Russell's paradox we do have a definition, since we use the property $x\notin x$, which is a fairly simple formula in the language of set theory. On the other hand, $x\notin A$ has **two** free variables, $x$ and $A$. So by saying $A=\{x\mid x\notin A\}$ you still have a free variable, and so you cannot apply Comprehension, and the previous paragraph takes place.

Comment: Ah, this makes it a bit clearer. But how can you show that $A$ is the empty set?

Comment: Oh, my bad. You're right. It's not the empty set. But as I wrote, it's not a definition, it's an equation.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, we can just say that $A$ can't exist because that would entail a contradiction, while preserving the General Comprehension Principle intact, as it guarantees only existence of sets defined by conditions without free variables, so my example which has one doesn't disprove it.

Comment: Yes. Comprehension is applied to formulas with one free variable, not with two. And while we can use parameters, these need to be sets that were already established as sets, not the set that we're trying to prove is a set (i.e. the proof is then tantamount to "Assume $A$ is a set, then the set of "everything not in $A$" exists, and we claim it is equal to $A$", which is senseless).

Comment: Perhaps such an $A$ can exist provided the universal set in the situation is the empty universe.

Comment: @paw88789: There are no empty universes.